# How can I create a struct in julia?

Tags: struct, julia

I am trying to create a structure, *txn*:

a)

```
struct txn
    txn_id::Int64
    bank::Char[20]
    branch::Char[20]
    teller::Char[20]
    customer::Char[20]
    account::Char[34]
    timestamp::DateTime
    dr_cr::Char[2]
    amount::Int64
end
```

gives

> Error: TypeError: in txn, in type definition, expected Type, got  Array{Char, 1}

b)

```
struct txn
    txn_id::Int64
    bank::Char(20)
    branch::Char(20)
    teller::Char(20)
    customer::Char(20)
    account::Char(34)
    timestamp::DateTime
    dr_cr::Char(2)
    amount::Int64
end
```

gives

> Error: TypeError: in txn, in type definition, expected Type, got Char

How can I create the struct in Julia?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Julia, an array of `Char`s is not equivalent to a `String`. The syntax `Char(80)` creates a single character:

```
julia> Char(80)
'P': ASCII/Unicode U+0050 (category Lu: Letter, uppercase)
```

And the syntax `Char[80, 81, 82]` creates an array of `Char`s:

```
julia> Char[80, 81, 82]
3-element Array{Char,1}:
 'P'
 'Q'
 'R'
```

We can see that an array of characters is not equivalent to a string (note that characters can also be represented using single quotes):

```
julia> ['a', 'b', 'c'] == "abc"
false
```

Try defining the string fields in your struct using the `String` type:

```
julia> struct Person
           name::String
       end

julia> p = Person("Bob")
Person("Bob")
```

Comment: Will there be any impact on memory by using type, String in struct?

Comment: Try `x = ['a', 'b', 'c']` and `y = "abc"` and compare `Base.summarysize(x)` to `Base.summarysize(y)`. You'll see that the array of characters actually takes up more memory than the string.

Comment: Specifically, this happens because `char`s are 4 bytes (utf32), but `string`s of english characters are 1 byte (utf8). This tradeoff makes sense, but is somewhat unintuitive